# Why can't I upload files via Firefox?

Tags: firefox, proxy, upload

I cannot attach files to emails in any email website, and I cannot upload files (say, to Google Drive) in Firefox - but I can attach files in Chrome. I think this means that there is a Firefox issue (though the issue persists with extensions disabled), not an Ubuntu issue per se. But on the other hand, the only reason I have seen for Firefox having an issue with communicating with the OS is proxy settings and I have NO proxy; and changing the Firefox network settings makes no difference to the problem. Firefox is latest, Ubuntu 18.04 is fully updated (well, except Wine won't update to 5.0, but presumably that is a separate issue).

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Boot with a LiveUSB and see if it works there.

Comment: Does the same problem persist if you use an email client like Thunderbird and do you have user rights on the file you are trying to attach?

Comment: peculiar. see if a window behind Firefox is opening up and you can't see it, when you choose to attach files. minimize your main Firefox window and check. report back :)

Comment: I do have user rights, but I do not have an email client installed. I have Discord chat and I can upload files there. I guess that is more support for it being a Firefox issue than an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: I tried to attach and minimized Firefox to look for a hidden window, but there is nothing hiding.

Comment: I booted with a Ubuntu 20.04LTS installation USB drive and Firefox worked normally with my gmail account: I could create an email and make an attachment

Comment: At this point, I would go ahead and upgrade to 20.04 if it were not for the fact that being unable to upgrade Wine is preventing that, and I am using Wine on a regular basis.

Comment: This problem resolved when I upgraded to 20.04 (which I was able to do only after uninstalling (but not purging) Wine. Fortunately, my Wine C:/ files remained intact and usable when I reinstalled Wine. Happy ending, but don't know what changed.